# elasticsearch: "More like this" combined with additional constraint

Tags: elasticsearch

I just bumped into "more like this" functionality/api. Is there a possibility to combine the result from more_like_this with some additional search constraint?

I have two following ES query which works:

```
POST /h/B/_search
{
   "query": {
      "more_like_this": {
         "fields": [
            "desc"
         ],
         "ids": [
            "511111260"
         ],
         "min_term_freq": 1,
         "max_query_terms": 25
      }
   }
}
```

Which returns

```
{
   "took": 16,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 3,
      "successful": 3,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 53,
      "max_score": 3.2860293,
      "hits": [
      ...
```

Which is fine but I need to specify additional constraint over other field of the underlying document which works separately fine:

```
POST /h/B/_search
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "must": {
            "match": {
               "Kind": "Pen"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I would love to combine those two to one, as the query should state: "Find a similar items to items labelled with Pen". I tried following with nested query but that gives me some error back:

```
POST /h/B/_search
{
   "query": {
      "more_like_this": {
         "fields": [
            "desc"
         ],
         "ids": [
            "511111260"
         ],
         "min_term_freq": 1,
         "max_query_terms": 25
      },
      "nested": {
         "query": {
            "bool": {
               "must": {
                  "match": {
                     "Kind": "Pen"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I tried several variant for combining those two search criteria but so far with no luck. 
If someone more experienced could provide some hint that would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`bool` queries](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) are used exactly for this purpose. A `bool must` is basically equivalent to the `Boolean AND` operation. Similarly you can use `bool should` for `Boolean OR` and `bool must_not` for `Boolean NOT` operations.

```
POST /h/B/_search
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "must": [
            {
               "more_like_this": {
                  "fields": [
                     "desc"
                  ],
                  "ids": [
                     "511111260"
                  ],
                  "min_term_freq": 1,
                  "max_query_terms": 25
               }
            },
            {
               "match": {
                  "Kind": "Pen"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```